# Update a column value with an other value in the same column

Tags: sql

I have fields like `A` and `B`. The data is is like:

```
+---+-----+
| A | B   |
+---+-----+
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | A   |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | A   |
| 3 | 300 |
| 3 | A   |
+---+-----+
```

Now i need the output data is:

```
+---+-----+
| A | B   |
+---+-----+
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |
| 3 | 200 |
+---+-----+
```

I need a SQL query in GP database.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?  sql-server, mysql, oracle?

Comment: What database? Whats a "GP Database", why "100" instead of "A"? you want the numbers? or based on an order (which you lack)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple update, that should work in any database:

```
update t
    set B = (select max(B) from t2 where B <> 'A' and t2.A = t.A)
    where B = 'A'
```